# Как создать регулярное выражение URL в Django

Tags: регулярные-выражения, django, url

У меня должно быть 5 страниц: pizza, hot, drinks, desserts, salads.
Вот по такому url ничего не работает:

```
r'^meals(?P<meal_name>[.]*)$'
```

Я хочу, чтоб можно было переходить по ссылке как-то так:
`/catalog/mealspizza` или `/catalog/mealshot`.

Comment: А вот так - `r'^meals(?P<meal_name>.*)$'`?

Comment: Заработало. Нужно было просто убрать квадратные скобки (а <meal_name> я вроде забыл написать в вопросе)

Comment: Это проблема форматирования, я поправил вопрос, чтобы угловые скобки отображались как надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражение `[.]` находит точку как символ (внутри символьных классов `.` не является специальным символом), а чтобы найти любой символ, нужно использовать `.`.

Используйте

```
r'^meals(?P<meal_name>.*)$'
```